# Can a row in an NSOutlineView be drug horizontally to change its rank

Tags: draggable, rank, nsoutlineview

I have an app with a single column NSOutlineView.

Vertical drag and drop works perfectly, but I can't get an item in the column to drag horizontally within that column, i.e. change its outline rank.  Will I have to track the mouse and programmatically change the rank?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I just discovered that an item can be dropped on the top of another item and that will demote it.  Not very intuitive, but I guess it will do.